# JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 3 path $[0]

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I get this exception:

`java.lang.Exception: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 3 path $[0]`

when tring to parse this json :

```
[
    "[{\"IdProduit\":1,\"NumeroSerie\":\"1234579657\",\"NomProduit\":\"Puce BigKing\",\"Prix\":200.0,\"Quantite\":500,\"IdModel\":1,\"IdModelNavigation\":{\"IdModel\":1,\"NomModel\":\"Puces\",\"Produit\":[],\"StockModel\":[]}},{\"IdProduit\":2,\"NumeroSerie\":\"12345687\",\"NomProduit\":\"Puce La Win\",\"Prix\":2000.0,\"Quantite\":60,\"IdModel\":1,\"IdModelNavigation\":{\"IdModel\":1,\"NomModel\":\"Puces\",\"Produit\":[],\"StockModel\":[]}},{\"IdProduit\":3,\"NumeroSerie\":\"124576328\",\"NomProduit\":\"Carte De Recharge 200DA\",\"Prix\":200.0,\"Quantite\":300,\"IdModel\":2,\"IdModelNavigation\":{\"IdModel\":2,\"NomModel\":\"Carte De Recharge\",\"Produit\":[],\"StockModel\":[]}}]"
]
```

Comment: Add codea for your api service (the interface class) and response object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your POJO structure to the question to make it clear. But maybe you need to remove the " inside your first json array.

So it will look like this

```
[
   [
      {
         "IdProduit":1,
         "NumeroSerie":"1234579657",
         "NomProduit":"Puce BigKing",
         "Prix":200.0,
         "Quantite":500,
         "IdModel":1,
         "IdModelNavigation":{
            "IdModel":1,
            "NomModel":"Puces",
            "Produit":[

            ],
            "StockModel":[

            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "IdProduit":2,
         "NumeroSerie":"12345687",
         "NomProduit":"Puce La Win",
         "Prix":2000.0,
         "Quantite":60,
         "IdModel":1,
         "IdModelNavigation":{
            "IdModel":1,
            "NomModel":"Puces",
            "Produit":[

            ],
            "StockModel":[

            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "IdProduit":3,
         "NumeroSerie":"124576328",
         "NomProduit":"Carte De Recharge 200DA",
         "Prix":200.0,
         "Quantite":300,
         "IdModel":2,
         "IdModelNavigation":{
            "IdModel":2,
            "NomModel":"Carte De Recharge",
            "Produit":[

            ],
            "StockModel":[

            ]
         }
      }
   ]
]
```

Or if you are using string literal in Java you need to add \ before ".
If this does not solve your problem please edit your question with your POJO